# lldb error: process launch failed: unable to locate lldb-server

Tags: lldb, clang++

I'm running Xubuntu 16.04. After installing lldb from the repositories, I get the following output when I try to use it:

```
lldb foo
(lldb) target create "foo"
Current executable set to 'foo' (x86_64).
(lldb) r
error: process launch failed: unable to locate lldb-server
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: For anyone with the *similar* error complaining about `unable to locate lldb-server-5.0.0`, the solution is slightly different. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46164427/472647).

Comment: For the error `unable to locate lldb-server-10.0.0`, the following worked for me: `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/llvm-10/bin/lldb-server /usr/lib/bin/lldb-server-10.0.0`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After an hour or so of fiddling around, I found the solution. I copied `/usr/bin/lldb-server-3.8` and named it `/usr/bin/lldb-server`. This is probably a problem with the ubuntu package.

Comment: I recommend setting an alternative rather than copying.: `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/lldb-server lldb-server /usr/bin/lldb-server-3.8 100`

Comment: @Matt saved my ass here; if someone reading this is, like me, trying to use Vagrant or another lightweight VM solution with Ubuntu Precise 12.04 LTS … here's how you get more recent LLVMs (and lldb!) installed on old Ubuntus: https://gist.github.com/ELLIOTTCABLE/ea68b9ec1257707bd625bf2955805e28

Comment: @Matt add it as an answer so we can rate it up. It seems a more smarter solution.

Answer (score 12):

I recommend setting an alternative rather than copying.  On Ubuntu, you can do this with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/lldb-server lldb-server /usr/bin/lldb-server-3.8 100
```