# lldb is not starting an application

Tags: c++, debugging, llvm, lldb, llvm-clang

this is my first experience in commandline mode of lldb. unsuccessful.

1. installed minimal kit with clang, lld, lldb v5 (ubuntu 16.04)
2. sample application built with clang.
3. trying to start:

> lldb applcation
>
> >run
>
> error: process launch failed: unable to locate lldb-server-5.0.0

so now the questions:

1. why lldb tries to run a server? this is not a remote debugging.
2. why lldb refers to 5.0.0 (and where to change this setting)? actually there was added symbolic links automiticaly  with xxx-5.0 suffix to all llvm utilities, but not with xxx-5.0.0. would be reasonable if this refers to lldb-server itself, without suffixes.
3. adding lldb-server-5.0.0 symlink doesn't solve the problem.

any idea how this should work?

by the way extra question - seems left/right/up/down arrows keys don't work in lldb console? instead of cursor moving it adds a codes

> (lldb) ^[[D^[[A^[[C^[[B

Comment: Is this any help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37107432/lldb-error-process-launch-failed-unable-to-locate-lldb-server ?

Comment: "why lldb tries to run a server" Nothing wrong with abstracting local and remote and any other type of debugging through the same server. Probably great for reducing duplicated code.

Comment: no . lldb-server is available in my case, in /usr/bin/ . but lldb looks for lldb-server-5.0.0, i don't know why,

Comment: This is the same issue (with the same resolution) as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37107432/lldb-error-process-launch-failed-unable-to-locate-lldb-server

Comment: @JimIngham, I'm having the same trouble, and concurring with the OP, that does *not* solve the problem. :(

Answer (score 5):

This is a [known bug with LLDB 5.0](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33150), apparently related to the Debian packaging. The workaround is *similar* to the question linked in the comments, but not the same. (And yes, having this exact problem, I've confirmed the solution.)

An `strace` reveals the problem...

> 1887 26838 access("/usr/lib/llvm-5.0/bin/lldb-server-5.0.0", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

That indicates exactly where that symlink is needed. Fixing it is as simple as a single terminal command...

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/lldb-server-5.0 /usr/lib/llvm-5.0/bin/lldb-server-5.0.0
```